# Get AutoGenerated Id from SQL Server using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to get the auto generated Id from my SQL Server 2012 with LINQ-to-SQL.

However when I assign the `Id` to a variable, after the submit I am getting a value of `Id = 0` every time. I'm guessing this is just the default `int` value and it's not actually grabbing the auto generated Id. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or how to properly pull it?

**Model View**

```
[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true )]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

**Repository**

```
var meoData = new MEO ()
{
    //a bunch of data assigned to the columns (Id is not assigned)
}
_dataContext.MEOs.InsertOnSubmit(meoData);
_dataContext.SubmitChanges();

//Create word doc
CreateWordDoc doc = new CreateWordDoc(meo);
int test = meo.Id;
```

The value of `meo.Id` is always returning as 0 and not its real auto generated Id.

Comment: You're inserting `meoData` but trying to read from `meo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you submitting meoData which will give you the id

try doing

```
 CreateWordDoc doc = new CreateWordDoc(meo);
 meo.Id= meoData.id
 int test = meo.Id;
```